# spring batch provide two type of range with FixedLengthTokenizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my application, I am getting two types of range in single Fixed length file for ex:

```
RECA 38148TG 5YNNABAC Corporate1 abc@xyzz.com
RECA 31148TG 5YNNABAC CorporateA xyz@asst.com
RECB 38143GM Corporate3 xyz@abqt.com
RECA 31148TN 5YNNABAC Corporate2 xyz@ncnt.com
```

In the above sample file there are two `recordType`: RECA and RECB. Both have different range of fields.I want to manage it through single itemReader according to `recordType`. So far I am trying it to following way:

```
public ItemReader<DataObj> itemReader(Resource inputData)  throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    FlatFileItemReader<DataObj> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    String[] tokens = {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"};
    tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
    tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[]{new Range(1, 4), new Range(5, 13), new Range(14, 14), new Range(15, 15)});
    reader.setResource(inputData);
    DefaultLineMapper<DataObj> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new RecordFieldSetMapper());
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return reader;

} 

@Bean
protected Step step1(@Qualifier("itemProcessor") ItemProcessor<DataObj, DataObj> processor, ItemWriter<DataObj> writer) throws ParseException {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("step1")
            .<DataObj, DataObj> chunk(10)
            .reader(itemReader(inputCsv))
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "firstBatchJob")
public Job job(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("firstBatchJob").start(step1).build();
}


@Bean
public ItemProcessor<DataObj, DataObj> itemProcessor() {
    return new CustomItemProcessor();
}

public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DataObj, DataObj> {

// ItemProcessor class
public DataObj process(DataObj item) {
    System.out.println("Processing..." + item);
    // INSERT INTO DB HERE
    return item;
}
}
// DataObj Class
public class DataObj{
private String col1;
private String col2;
private String col3;
private String col4;
private String col5;
```

I want to achieve column range according to `recordType` condition. for ex in `itemReader` :

```
public ItemReader<Libor> itemReader(Resource inputData)  throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    FlatFileItemReader<Libor> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
   if (recType == 'recA'){
        String[] tokens = {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"};
        tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
        tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[]{new Range(1, 4), new Range(5, 13), new Range(14, 14), new Range(15, 15)}); 
   }
   if (recType == 'recB'){
        String[] tokens = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
        tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
        tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[]{new Range(1, 4), new Range(5, 13), new Range(14, 14), }); 
   }
   // Rest of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recordType` is a runtime information, you cannot use it at configuration time when setting up the reader.

You can use a [PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer.html) with two delegate tokenizers: one for records starting with `RECA` and one for records starting with `RECB`. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizerTests.java).

Once you have the composite tokenizer, you can set in on the `FlatFileItemReader`.